# Do Sidekicks have a level?

Tags: dice-masters

Do the Sidekick dice (NPCs in D&D) have a level? They don't have a card, and only one character face. Some actions and cards target characters but only of a certain level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Side kicks only have one level and can not be spun up or down. It is in the official rules:

> Sidekicks are the .... character side. Sidekick characters have no powers, and only the one level.

(edited one word)

Comment: This is correct. Thus sidekicks are affected by anything that affects level one character. They cannot be spun up or down a level.